# Flutter + Provider + FutureBuilder Null check operator on initialization app

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

The error is occurring Null check operator used on a null value with the context used to get the provider.
The error happens to some users.

Occurs in line:

```
`await _userDataController.loadSync(context, assinaturaController: _assinaturaController);`
```

Error: Null check operator used on a null value

```
`#0 State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:958)#1
_HomePageState.getData (package:appxxxx/pages/home_page.dart:211)<asynchronous suspend>#2
_FutureBuilderState._subscribe.<anonymous close> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:624)           <asynchronous suspend>`
```

follows the complete code of the method loaded in the future:

```
`
Future<bool> getData() async {
try {
_abaController = context.read<AbaController>();
_assinaturaController = context.read<AssinaturaController>();
var _userDataController = context.read<UserDataController>();
isOnline = await Conexao.isOnline();

//test your internet connection online
if (isOnline == false)
   return Future<bool>.value(false);

//get current date and time from server
      await DataUtils.loadDateTimeServer();
//initialize remote config
await GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().loadData();
///Checks if app update is mandatory and aborts
int versaoAppLocal = int.parse((await PackageInfo.fromPlatform()).buildNumber);
int versaoAppRemoteConfig = GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().versaoMinimaApp;
if (versaoAppLocal < versaoAppRemoteConfig){
  atualizacaoAppObrigatoria = true;
  return Future<bool>.value(false);
}

///Check if the environment is under maintenance and abort
if (GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().isAmbienteEmManutencao){
  isAmbienteEmManutencao = true;
  return Future<bool>.value(false);
}

//retrieves instance Firebase auth and sets user logged in provider
await GetIt.I<AuthService>().init(context);
//initializes the subscriptions plugin (revenuecat) and sets if the user is a subscriber or not
await GetIt.I<PurchaseService>().load(context);
//initialize notifications plugin settings
await _initializeNotificationsSetttings();
//call service to load a list of session data
await TickersHelper.load();
//ERROR HERE ↓
await _userDataController.loadSync(context, assinaturaController: _assinaturaController);
_requestPermissions();
_configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
_configureSelectNotificationSubject();
_loadAndSetTabIcons();
await GetIt.I<UsuarioApiService>().callIncluirTokenPush();
await GetIt.I<NotificacoesHelper>().programaNotifications(context);


await _showDialogUmpCMP();
await _autenticaBiometria();
await _initDynamicLinks();

} catch (ex, stack) {
   ....
}
`
```

full boot without errors. the informed line must always run at startup

Comment: "Null check operator used on a null value" always means a `!` was used on a variable with value `null`. Since you don't have any `!` in that piece of code I doubt the error is in the part you showed

Comment: did you see the error stack?
Null check is here package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:958)#1

Comment: Sounds like you might need to check that your widget is "mounted" before doing whatever you are trying to do.  Try wrapping the call inside an "if (mounted) {" block.

Comment: the problem with doing this is that the method always has to be executed when opening, I can't enter it without executing it.